# Maths behind web analytics

Tags: math, analytics

Are there any good resources related to the maths behind web analytics? What are the key processes. Is there anything to explain how this maths gets turned into software?

Answer (score 1):

Read [Programming Collective Intelligence](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596529325).  It's a great book that will give you a lot of details.

Answer (score 0):

Refer to Google Analytics FAQ [HERE](http://www.google.com/support/analytics/bin/topic.py?hl=en&topic=10977)

Answer (score 0):

There is a *lot* to web analytics.  Just to give one example, I did a tutorial on [Effective A/B Testing](http://elem.com/~btilly/effective-ab-testing/) a few years back.  And A/B testing is only one piece of in tracking and optimizing website performance.